# Simplifying $f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\cos^{-1}(\cos x)+x^n(1-\{x\})}{1+x^n}$

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives, trigonometry, continuity

$f(x)$ is an odd periodic function with period $6$ such that $f(3) = 0$ and, for $x\in[0, 3)$,
$$f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\cos^{-1}(\cos x)+x^n(1-\{x\})}{1+x^n}$$
(where "$\{\cdot\}$" denotes fractional part function).

I need to simplify the function and then use it to find discontinuity and other stuff but I wasn't able to even begin the simplifying beyond $\cos^{-1}\cos x = x$.

I tried solving it for specific values of $x$ but that doesn't give me the function for the domain so it proved useless.

Please help me out.

([original problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqpKz.png))

Comment: yes f(x) is that limit for the given domain of [0,3)

Comment: So what is the problem here? Do we have to find f(x) or discontinuity at some point?

Comment: 1. Number of points of discontinuity of f(x) in the interval (–9, 9) is

Comment: 2. the number of points where f(x) is discontinuous and non-differentiable respectively in (0, 11)

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb the above 2 questions were in the form of linked comprehension. I know how to find those but I wasn't able to solve the limit so i asked to find f(x). any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the property 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x^n = \begin{cases} 0, x<1 &\\
1, x=1 & \\
\infty, x >1\end{cases}$$

You can now substitute the value of $x^n$ for $x \le 1$. For $x > 1$, divide numerator and denominator by $x^n$ to obtain $1-\{x\}$

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x, 0<x\le1 & \\ 
1-\{x\}, x>1\end{cases}$$

After this point, it becomes easy to find the values of f(x) for all other numbers in ${R}$ using the property that it is odd and that it has a period of 6.

Comment: i wanted to know how did you solve this. so  arc cos (cosx) becomes x and then you take x^n common from the numerator and denominator and its cancelled. so you're left with 1-{x}. Is this correct? now how did you split this for the domain.

Comment: I edited the answer to be more verbose.

Comment: yes i understood thanks!

Comment: actually one last thing. number of points of non differentiability in (0,11) should be 10 right as at each integer there's either a sharp change in graph or a discontinuity. The points of discontinuity will be 2,4,8 and 10

Comment: @ShauryaGoyal yes.